# Protect files/images direct download from file server or shared folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fileserver

I want to protect the file/images which are available on a file server(separate machine). For uploading the file, I'm planning to use a memory stream and write it to file server's shared location. I hope that using a memory stream is the best for performance.

While displaying the images to user, the requirement is to provide an anchor tag with `href a href="FileServer/sharedFolderName/image1" />` so that images can be viewed in the browser itself, or the user can download it.

The user should not allowed to directly download the file by entering the `FileServer/sharedFolderName/image1.png` in an browser, or in any other way.

Comment: There's really no fool-proof way of doing this. If the browser can display the image, then someone can download it if they really want to.

Comment: Cant I set the no access permission in the shared folder for all and only the admin can access it. Then impersonate the admin privilege in asp.net MVC 3. Instead of using href let me know if we have any other control will allow the images to render in the browser